# Filter mapping is not working in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, authentication, servlets

I have created a filter in my application to take care of login/logout scenario. The filter mapping is not working. In my `web.xml`, if I put`<url-pattern>/LoginServlet/*</url-pattern>`, filter mapping works, but if I put a name of the jsp, then it doesn't work `<url-pattern>/LoginServlet/list.jsp</url-pattern>`. I don't want to call the filter for all jsps.

This is my filter.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter{

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : Start");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 111111");


        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 222222");
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            //response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
            //response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_ELMS/login.jsp");
        }else {
            System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 33333333");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is my `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>edu.umd.enpm613.helper.StartupListner</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.umd.enpm613.servlet.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.umd.enpm613.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>StudentServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.umd.enpm613.servlet.StudentServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

LoginServlet is:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : Start");
        LoginDTO returnedDTO = null;
        String userEmailId = request.getParameter("userid");
        try {
            request.getSession(true).setAttribute("user", userEmailId);
            String userPassword = request.getParameter("password");

            LoginDTO loginDto = new LoginDTO();
            loginDto.setUserEmailId(userEmailId);
            loginDto.setUserPassword(userPassword);

            returnedDTO = LoginImpl.getUserCategory(loginDto);

            String category = returnedDTO.getUserCategory();

            if (category.equals(ELMSConstants.CATEGORY_STUDENT)) {
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("student_home.jsp").forward(request,response);
                System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : Start" +request.getContextPath());
                System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : Start" +request.getRequestURI());
                System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : Start" + request.getRequestURL());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }
            if (category.equals(ELMSConstants.CATEGORY_TEACHER)) {
                System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : 22222222222");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("professor_home.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }


        }catch (ELMSException exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : error message is" + exp.getMessage());

            if (exp.getMessage().equals(ELMSException.USER_NEED_TO_CHANGE_PASSWORD)) {
                System.out.println("LoginServlet : doPost : 1111111111");
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", exp.getMessage());
                request.setAttribute("userName", userEmailId);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("changePassword.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }

            if (!exp.getMessage().equals(ELMSException.USER_NEED_TO_CHANGE_PASSWORD)) {
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", exp.getMessage());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have given the correct jsp path? /LoginServlet/list.jsp may not be the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter should bypass the login page because it has not a security restriction, also it would allow you to map all URLs without infinite loop.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : Start");
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 111111");


    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    //bypass the login page and login servlet

    if (request.getRequestURI().indexof("login.jsp") >= 0 ||
      request.getRequestURI().indexof("/LoginServlet") >= 0){
      System.out.println("LoginFilter : bypass the login");
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 222222");
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        //response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
        //response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_ELMS/login.jsp");
      } else {
        System.out.println("LoginFilter : doFilter : 33333333");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It takes care of the infinite loop when server starts. The problem is when I login on login.jsp, it directly goes to the filter. I get the trace that you put, and it then it goes back to login page again. It never goes to LoginServlet. My LoginServlet forwards the request to list.jsp, that flow is not working now.

Comment: Map a servlet with `/LoginServlet/*`.

Comment: do you mean filter? That's how I have mapped. This is my mapping.  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginServlet/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: No, I mean a servlet mapping.

Comment: filter mapping?   <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> and servlet mapping   <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginServlet/*</url-pattern> ?

Comment: Yes, and post `login.jsp`.

Comment: I have edited my question and changed the web.xml. Can you please check if it's correct. It's still not working for me.

Comment: Do you also want to check my login.jsp file?

Comment: Does your form submit to servlet? If yes, then servlet should handle authentication.

Comment: yes it does.. so my LoginServlet should implement filter

Comment: I didn't get what you mean *LoginServlet should implement filter*. Could you post `LoginServlet`?

Comment: I posted my LoginServlet.

Answer (score 0):

According to Java [Servlet Specification](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr053/)

> In the web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> • A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’
>   postfix is used for path mapping.
>
> • A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
>   mapping.
>
> • A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>   servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>   request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
>
> • All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So you cannot directly map servlet or filter with file like: /LoginServlet/list.jsp . Possible solution is to put your list.jsp file to individual folder like /LoginServlet/Security/list.jsp
And map it:

```
<url-pattern>/LoginServlet/Security/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I have moved all the jsps that are eligible to <url-pattern>/jsps/*</url-pattern>. It's still not working. If I do <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>, it again works. But I don't want my login.jsp to be part of this, because it becomes infinite loop then.